# Is this an excessive number of active sessions on a ColdFusion server?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have recently been having some ColdFusion (10) stability issues on one of my servers. The basic server details are as follows:

2.6GHz dual processor, 6GB RAM, Windows Server 2008 R2

The hosting company who manage this server have said that there are too many active sessions on the server and that this could be the cause of the issue.

I have been monitoring the sessions on the server and at peak times there may be 1500-2000 active sessions taking up about 1.5-2mb of memory in total. The sessions are stored in memory and for the most part these are real user sessions as we run some code to detect bots and issue them with very short sessions.

Given the above information does this seem like an unreasonable number of active sessions and session memory usage? Any advice would be appreciated, please let me know if any more information would be helpful.

Comment: Can we have some more info - How do you store your sessions? in-memory/database something else? Ah those real users or bot created sessions etc, is the database being hammered...

Comment: The sessions are stored in memory. For the most part those are real user sessions as we run some code to detect the most common bots and issue them with very short sessions.

Comment: From what you've said, then it doesn't seem unreasonable

Comment: Too many sessions can cause stability issues or freeze a webserver. In general i try to keep the session timeout as short as possible. That being said 2000 active sessions using a total of 2 mb is way to little to cause any performance issues (IMO). Could you describe your 'stability issues' and is this a dedicated webserver?

Comment: **Server Settings > Client Variables** setting change from registry to a datasource can help you to some extend with this issue.

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan I am asking about session variables not client variables. I don't use client variables at all.